# Can I load a domain in my iFrame and when you click a link, it opens in the parent window, not the iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Similar to Stumbleupon, if you load random domains (ones that I do not own) and want to have the links within that page not just change within the iframe, but change on the parent url.

If that's hard to understand here's more layman terms:

URL: `mywebsite.com/reddit.com`
opens iframe on my website showing: reddit.com
click link within the iframe (showing reddit.com).

rather than it loading the new page in the iframe, can it load in the parent window at `mywebsite.com/reddit.com/newlink`

which would then open the iframe in my website, but would allow me to track what URL is being view and thus allowing me to perform my site-specific functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in short, it cant happen. external sites are made to open links relative to their sites. there is no way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the link target to `_top`. `<a href='www.someothersite.com' target='_top'>Link</a>`

edit: Sorry, mis-read something. You can not edit the page on the other site through the iframe to change the target of the links. This is why on places like google images or stumbleupon they have an "X" in the corner that takes you to the page in the iframe.

If you could modify external pages, that would be a major phishing security risk as anyone could then make a page that is just an iframe to your bank but collects whatever you type into the username/password boxes.

Answer (score -1):

In the old days if you made a page with frames you could specify what section your links took you to. Modifying links that aren't under your control is possible but rather a task and a half.

To use frames you could specify your target= within your  tag. Each frame is named on creation to make it easy.

That's an old approach. Hope it helps

Comment: Then how do proxy sites work. It's true it isn't original. But it is possible with downloading entire pages, caching and displaying hence the possible.

Comment: If a site is _truly_ proxying then it does indeed download the target site, parse the contents and then hand it to the client for rendering with appropriate code change on-the-fly. Iframes, however, can only be accessed via JS/Similar if the source domain matches the source of the JS - ie if it's your own site. Give it a try on a modern browser...